# WPF - Behaviour of ListviewItemFocus selected by arrow key doesn't work like mouseclick

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, border, listviewitem

I would like to paint the dotted border of an listview item when I select it with mouse click.
You can see only the dotted border when i select the listview item with arrowkey.
Here you are an example:
[image: Focus when you select with arrow key]
[image: Focus when you do the mouseclcik on it]
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The dotted rectangle that appears when you focus your item with the keyboard is the `FocusVisualStyle`. You should read more [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/01/29/render-transforms-and-focus-visuals/), in this link you can find the default style that looks much like your screenshots. You have to add it to your `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate` and disable the default `FocusVisualStyle` for selected item by setting it to `{x:Null}`.

**Edit:** forgot to add, you should not do any of this. You don't want to confuse the FocusVisualStyle with Selected Item Style.